# How to view the HTTP headers, response code and html content using urllib3 in Python?

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I am interested in retrieving the response code, body and HTTP headers using urllib3. The previous code which I had written was in Python 2 and now I have to rewrite it for Python 3.

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager();
response = http.request('GET', 'http://192.168.43.131:8000')
print(response)
```

I tried different sources, but can someone point me in the right direction of the give a few pointers?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this:

```
import json

import urllib3 # pip install urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', 'http://192.168.43.131:8000')
print(response.status)
print(response.headers)
print(json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))) # body
```

Convert body to json with **[orjson](https://github.com/ijl/orjson/)**:

```
import orjson  # pip install orjson

import urllib3 # pip install urllib3

response = http.request('GET', 'http://192.168.43.131:8000')

print(orjson.loads(response.data)) # body
```

doc: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

Comment: The json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8')) is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have found this?

https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#response-content

That would suggest you could get the status code, for example, with

```
print(response.status)
```